# submitting forms from unconventional pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where users can create survey questions. Everything works fine if the forms are submitted from the pages you'd expect if you set up the urls like the following, which I have

```
resources :surveys
```

This is what happens in the server when I submit a form to the create action.

```
Started POST "/surveys" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-18 16:32:39 -0800
Processing by SurveysController#create as HTML
```

However, in the show action of the Users controller, I also included the code that you'd expect to find in the 'new' action of the survey controller. This was done so that users can create survey questions from their own profile. However, when the form is submitted, it's now submitted as a "GET" request and it's being processed in the show action of the users controller, so obviously the survey's not getting created

```
Started GET "/twitterusers/1? whole bunch of data-passed-in-the-url-bar-via-GET-ommitted
Processing by TwitterusersController#show as HTML
```

This is what the form looks like (i haven't included the partials).

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name, "Name your Quiz" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%#= @survey.questions %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
       <%= render "question_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Question", f, :questions %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

I'm wondering if there's changes that I can make to the form to accomplish what I'm trying to do. If this isn't advisable (going against Rails conventions), please explain what you'd do in my situation.

Update -- code from show action of users controller. Survey has_many questions (accepts_nested_attributes_for) and questions does the same with answers. It creates a form with two sets of questions (each with four fields for answers)

```
   def show
      @twitteruser = Twitteruser.find(params[:id])
      2.times do
      questions = @survey.questions.build
      4.times { questions.answers.build }
      end
    end
```

This is the create action of the surveys controller (which it's not submitting to if I submit from show action)

```
 def create
    @survey = current_user.surveys.build(params[:survey])

    if @survey.save
      redirect_to twitteruser_path(current_user), :notice => "Successfully created"
      # redirect_to @survey, :notice => "Successfully created survey."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
 end
```

Comment: Can you add the code from the show action of your Users Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following:

1.) In your view, change `@survey` to `Survey.new`

or

2.) In your `Users#show` action, add `@survey = Survey.new`

Comment: If I change @survey to Survey.new in the view, then it doesn't create any of the question or answer fields that the do...end did in the controller. However adding  Survey.new in the controller isn't fixing the problem either.

Comment: Are you adding `@survey = Survey.new` inside of the `do` loop? And can you tell me if, on submit, it is now being processed by the Surveys Controller?

Comment: I'm not putting it inside the do loop. It's actually the same way now that it is in the new action of the Surveys controller (which works). When I submit now, I'm getting a "Request-URI Too Large" error--too much data passing in the uri bar. There must be something else wrong.